# Trying to open an outlook oft template stored on Sharepoint

Tags: vba, templates, sharepoint, outlook

I'm have an issue with my code trying to open an outlook template (*.oft) on sharepoint. I admit I'm terrible with coding so please excuse any and all mistakes. I'm still learning and since I'm learning by reading other peoples codes its slow going. Here is what I have:

```
Private Sub Command459_Click()
Set myOlApp = CreateObject("internet explorer.Application")
Set myItem = myOlApp.CreateItemFromTemplate("http://sharepoint/teams/plbt/Support%20Documents/OutageTypeSP1.oft")
myItem.Display
End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!
Thanks!!
-Deke

Answer (score 0):

CreateItemFromTemplate takes a file path, not an HTTP url. You need to download the file locally first, then it open it using CreateItemFromTemplate.

Comment: So is there a way to open a file from sharepoint without having it stored locally? I'm trying to setup a button that when used will open the oft file saved in sharepoint.

Comment: No, it needs to be accessing through the file system API.